# Is mysql table not matching sqlalchemy model can cause an error?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Mysql User table: `user_id int (pk), name varchar, last_name varchar`
SQLAlchemy model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id     = Column('user_id',INTEGER, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    name   = Column('name',String(256), nullable=False) 
    lastname   = Column('last_name',String(256), nullable=False)
```

If I want to add columns in my User table like `phone_number` and `address` which are not going to be used by my application. Do I need to change necessary my model of sqlalchemy or is it not harmful?

Comment: You could use the [automap extension](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html) to reflect the database tables rather than having to keep model code in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have add the columns into your User class. But if you add data into the database using sqlachemy, it will construct the rows using only the fields from the class User, so if you do not have the defaults set in the database table definition, it may cause an error.

EDIT: You should be safe if you only use the model to query the database.

Comment: Thank you @Petr . Maybe I didn't express myself in a proper way. I don't create the db from sqlalchemy. The db is created separately . I use the model in my code when I want to do some queries. In this case is it a problem if the model is not matching the new db in mysql (with address and phone_number) even if I don't use it in the query when I call user model?

Comment: Ah, I probably did not express myself too well too :-) I did not mean defining/changing the  schema from sqlalchemy, but just adding rows.